# Twitter Bootstrap and ASP.NET GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, .net-4.0, twitter-bootstrap

I am having aproblem using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables) from my ASP.NET application. When I use the `table table-striped` css class to my `asp:GridView` control, **it treats the *Header* of the table as a *Row***.

### My GridView

#### ASP.NET MarkUp

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvUsers" runat="server" 
    CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" GridLines="None" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="ID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
    </Columns>
    <RowStyle CssClass="cursor-pointer" />
</asp:GridView>
```

#### Result

[image: Header treated as a row]

```
<table id="cphMainContent_dgvUsers" class="table table-hover table-striped" 
       cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Username</th>
            <th scope="col">First Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cursor-pointer">
            <td>user1</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>User 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cursor-pointer">
            <td>user2</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>User 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cursor-pointer">
            <td>user3</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>User 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### It should be like this

[image: It should be like this]

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I make the header of my `asp:GridView` be treated as a Header by Twitter Bootstrap?
My code is in C#, framework 4, build in VS2010 Pro.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to set `useaccessibleheader` attribute of the gridview to `true` and also then also specify a `TableSection` to be a header after calling the `DataBind()` method on you GridView object. So if your grid view is `mygv`

```
mygv.UseAccessibleHeader = True
mygv.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
```

This should result in a proper formatted grid with `thead` and `tbody` tags

Comment: I throws a **NullReferenceException** in the line `dgvUsers.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;`.

Comment: Thanks, I should just put that line after the `dgv.DataBind()` binding of data to my `GridView` and the *NullReferenceException* is now gone. It now work. Thanks again.

Comment: @JohnIsaiahCarmona Do note that the HeaderRow will still be null when there aren't any rows to display (when the datasource is empty)

Comment: For anyone coming here later, take not that "True" should be "true"

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 steps to resolve this:

1. Add `UseAccessibleHeader="true"` to Gridview tag:

   ```
   <asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" UseAccessibleHeader="true">
   ```
2. Add the following Code to the `PreRender` event:

```
Protected Sub MyGridView_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyGridView.PreRender
    Try
        MyGridView.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Note setting Header Row in `DataBound()` works only when the object is databound, any other postback that doesn't databind the gridview will result in the gridview header row style reverting to a standard row again. PreRender works everytime, just make sure you have an error catch for when the gridview is empty.

Answer (score 4):

Just for the record, I got borders in the table and to get rid of it I needed to set following properties in the GridView:

```
GridLines="None"
CellSpacing="-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add property of show header in gridview

```
 <asp:GridView ID="dgvUsers" runat="server" **showHeader="True"** CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" GridLines="None" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

and in columns add header template

```
<HeaderTemplate>
                   //header column names
</HeaderTemplate>
```