# BootStrap CSS for GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to apply Bootstrap css to my grid view.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSI" runat="server" CellPadding="6"  
     CssClass= "table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" />
```

The result is pretty basic tabular structure. Can anyone tell me if there are any other styles available for professional grid like alternate colors, header, row highlighter..

Comment: Are you using a table for the grid?

Comment: yes. Gidview generates table only

Comment: Grid View is asp.net in built control which automatically generates tabular data for the input passed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm also trying to style my GridView with Bootstrap. If you want to use the Bootstrap predefine CSS Style, here are your options: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables. You can add color to selected row by applying Optional row classes (success, error, warning, info). If you still want to change the table style to your need, you will have to use ID and create a specific css class for this ID.

There is an header problem with the asp.net Gridview, but it was solve in a previous post, here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/12362569, it works for me. Though, I'm still looking for a solution to apply Bootstrap style to the GridView pagination.